# Output total number of ways to invest in 10 stocks if you can only invest 10$ increments

Tags: java, combinatorics, counting

I got this as an interview question at AMEX and while visualizing the answer is pretty easy, I had a tough time figuring out how to actually generate it.

Does anybody have a good way of solving a combination problem like this via Divide and Conquer?

Example Output:

The arrays represents the 10 different stocks and how much of your $100 you've invested in each.

(100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) etc

(90, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (90, 0, 10, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0 ,0) etc.

for every possible combination.

Comment: I would suggest using a form of a truth table to figure this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion.

At each stock `i` you have an amount left to spend, and you can spend anywhere up to this amount in increments of 10. For the last store, you have to spend the remaining.

I would call a listener, callback or print the array after each combination.

```
public static void printCombinations(int stocks, int cash, int cashMultiple) {
    int[] amounts = new int[stocks];
    printCombinations(amounts, 0, cash, cashMultiple);
}

public static void printCombinations(int[] amounts, int n, int cash, int cashMultiple) {
    if (n == amounts.length-1) {
        amounts[n] = cash;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(amounts));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= cash ; i += cashMultiple) {
        amounts[n] = i;
        printCombinations(amounts, n+1, cash - i, cashMultiples);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was trying to solve this iteratively which is why I wasn't able to figure it out.